# Why wasn't Gambit included in the X-Men Cinematic Universe?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe

I am currently re-watching the X-Men animated series of 1992. As I remembered, there is no special focus on any specific X-Men character in the series. The X-Men appearance order in the [intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IzSGvXc_PM) is

- Cyclops
- Wolverine
- Rogue
- Storm
- Beast
- Gambit
- Jubilee
- Jean Grey
- Professor X

Among the X-Men featuring in the intro, Jubilee is given no substantial role in the movies, while Gambit is included only as a side character in *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*.

Is there any specific reason expressed by the actors, directors, producers or any other relevant person explaining why Gambit was mostly omitted from the X-Men Cinematic Universe?

Comment: Because the *Gambit* movie is currently in "development hell" - https://screenrant.com/x-men-channing-tatum-gambit-movie/

Comment: @Paulie_D Have the producers ever expressed that they wanted to use Gambit in a separate movie? I mean even the most boring X-Men, Storm is there, but the most fun X-Men is not :)

Comment: It IS a separate movie...they just can't get it made yet.

Comment: In addition, one of the most significant and memorable aspects of Gambit's story, especially when active with the X-Men, is his relationship with Rogue. Given that in the first X-Men movie they paired Logan with Rogue as a friend/mentee (instead of with one of the other mutants he actually mentored in a significant way, Kitty Pryde or Jubilee), they couldn't really pair up the two in that movie. Since then, Rogue hasn't been a big part of any of the movies. Something set in the past, or featuring Gambit as a standalone character, avoids that issue.

Comment: @RDFozz I disagree. Gambit is fun because of his personality, rivalry with Wolverine and because of the unpredictable way he uses his powers. Granted that in rivalry Gambit is replaced by Cyclops, who was kind of above such petty things in the animated series, Gambit would still be quite fun. Finally, Rogue could easily be found by Gambit and brought to the mansion in the first movie to assert the friend/mentee relationship. The only drawback would be the scene where Rogue takes Wolverine's power after he stabbed her because of his nightmare would have made way less sense.

Comment: Not saying Gambit isn't fun, by any means. Given the first movie's focus on Wolverine, a split of focus between him and the Gambit/Rogue relationship would have required a longer movie. For that matter, I'm not saying that I necessarily agree with this thinking - it's more a matter of how studio execs, etc., might think of things.

Comment: @RDFozz The whole franchise is on Wolverine imho. Besides, Wolverine-Rogue focus constituted quite little part of the first movie. Anyway, it is obvious that the first three movies were planned together. Adding Gambit would change the plans a lot, but it would still be possible. It would be much easier to omit Storm btw, she has the least connection with other X-Men.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably largely due to the fact that his character was one of many points that comic fans reacted negatively to in X-Men Origins: Wolverine. Back in 2014, I believe, there were attempts to try and rectify this with a solo Gambit film, with Channing Tatum in the lead, the idea being that maybe they could redeem the character like they did with Deadpool.

However, the solo Gambit movie went through development hell, and issues regarding directors, writers, and scripts caused constant delays. Also, since the recent Disney-Fox merger, Deadpool is the only character not being recast, and The New Mutants film seems to be getting released next year, although that largely just seems to be able to use it to make some additional money, as that film was pretty much finished.

Answer (score 3):

Gambit has had his own eponymous film in development. This would likely have been his first major appearance, but [it's been a troubled production](https://screenrant.com/gambit-movie-cancelled-development-hell/). Prior to that, he had a brief scene in [*X-Men Origins: Wolverine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_Origins:_Wolverine).